# Classification results depend on random_state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, boosting

I want to implement a AdaBoost model using scikit-learn (sklearn). My question is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-numberin-scikit-learn) but it is not totally the same. As far as I understand, the random_state variable described in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) is for randomly splitting the training and testing sets, according to the previous link. So if I understand correctly, my classification results should not be dependent on the seeds, is it correct? Should I be worried if my classification results turn out to be dependent on the random_state variable?

Comment: Related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263999/is-random-state-a-parameter-to-tune

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classification scores will depend on `random_state`. As @Ujjwal rightly said, it is used for splitting the data into training and test test. Not just that, a lot of algorithms in scikit-learn use the `random_state` to select the subset of features, subsets of samples, and determine the initial weights etc.

For eg.

- Tree based estimators will use the `random_state` for random selections of features and samples (like `DecisionTreeClassifier, RandomForestClassifier`).
- In clustering estimators like [Kmeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans), `random_state` is used to initialize centers of clusters.
- SVMs use it for initial probability estimation
- Some feature selection algorithms also use it for initial selection
- And many more...

Its mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html) that:

> If your code relies on a random number generator, it should never use functions like numpy.random.random or numpy.random.normal. This approach can lead to repeatability issues in tests. Instead, a numpy.random.RandomState object should be used, which is built from a `random_state` argument passed to the class or function.

Do read the following questions and answers for better understanding:

- [Choosing random_state for sklearn algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097921/choosing-random-state-for-sklearn-algorithms)
- [confused about random_state in decision tree of scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158003/confused-about-random-state-in-decision-tree-of-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 3):

It does matter. When your training set differs then your trained state also changes. For a different subset of data you can end up with a classifier which is little different from the one trained with some other subset.

Hence, you should use a constant seed like `0` or another integer, so that your results are reproducible.

Comment: so should i believe the prediction? or should i treat this random_state as another hyperparameter? it really doesn't make a lot of sense to have different prediction because of different seeds for pseudo random number generator...

Comment: It makes a perfect sense because due to random seeding everytime you train over a different subset of data. It is not a hyper-parameter really. you should just set it to some fixed number and then across systems you will be able to reproduce ur numbers.

Comment: right... i understand. so if the random_state = 0 and random_state = 10 give different results, which one should i trust? given that my dataset is sort of noisy, but not completely.

Comment: generally the seed which gives closest accuracy to average accuracy should be used for safety. If u find it useful, pls accept my answer

Comment: thanks, but i'd like to give other ppl chances. your answer is great, i appreciate it!

Comment: Correct answer is not  going to change, but ok. That's fine.

Comment: you could train with different random states and average the results of the models....probably not as good as averaging another type of model with it though.  as far as which prediction to "trust"...it depends on what's at stack if you're wrong.