# Why does sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV return random results on every execution?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was trying to get the optimum features for a decision tree classifier over the Iris dataset using `sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV`. I used StratifiedKFold (`sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold`) for cross-validation, since my data was biased. But on every execution of `GridSearchCV`, it returned a different set of parameters.
Shouldn't it return the same set of optimum parameters given that the data and the cross-validation was same every single time?

Source code follows:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

decision_tree_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()

parameter_grid = {'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'max_features': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(all_classes, n_folds=10)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(decision_tree_classifier, param_grid = parameter_grid,
                          cv = cross_validation)

grid_search.fit(all_inputs, all_classes)

print "Best Score: {}".format(grid_search.best_score_)
print "Best params: {}".format(grid_search.best_params_)
```

Outputs:

```
Best Score: 0.959731543624
Best params: {'max_features': 2, 'max_depth': 2}

Best Score: 0.973154362416
Best params: {'max_features': 3, 'max_depth': 5}

Best Score: 0.973154362416
Best params: {'max_features': 2, 'max_depth': 5}

Best Score: 0.959731543624
Best params: {'max_features': 3, 'max_depth': 3}
```

This is an excerpt from an Ipython notebook which I made recently, with reference to **Randal S Olson's** notebook, which can be found [here](https://github.com/darthv115/Machine-Learning-and-Data-Science-Projects/blob/master/Iris_Classification/Iris%20Classification.ipynb).

**Edit**:
Its not the `random_state` parameter of `StratifiedKFold` which results in varied results but rather the `random_state` parameter of `DecisionTreeClassifer` which randomly initializes the tree and gives varied results (refer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)). As for `StratifiedKFold`, as long as the `shuffle` parameter is set to `False` (default), it generates the same training-test split (refer documentation).

Answer (score 2):

The training results depend on the way the train data is splitted in cross validation. Each time you run, the data is splitted randomly and hence you observe minor differences in your answer. 
You should use the [`random_state` parameter of StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) to make sure that the train data is splitted exactly same way each time.

See my other answer to know more about randomstate:

- [Classification results depend on random_state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476032/classification-results-depend-on-random-state/42477052#42477052)

Comment: Its not the `random_state` parameter of `StratifiedKFold` which results in varied results but rather the `random_state` parameter of 'DecisionTreeClassifer` which randomly initializes the tree randomly and gives varied results. As for `StratifiedKFold`, as long as the `shuffle` parameter is set to `False` (default), it generates the same training-test split. I checked this result in a separate Ipython notebook which can be found [here](https://github.com/darthv115/Machine-Learning-and-Data-Science-Projects/blob/master/Iris_Classification/Rectifications_to_original_notebook.ipynb).

Comment: using a particular random state solved this issue of returning different results on every execution of gridserachcv. I was using it for random forest classifier.

Answer (score 1):

For each run,the cv randomly split the train and validation set therefore results of each would be different.