# Role of random_state in train_test_split and classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Based on this answer: [Random state (Pseudo-random number)in Scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-numberin-scikit-learn), if I use the same integer (say 42) as `random_state`, then each time it does train-test split, it should give the same split (i.e. same data instances in train during each run, and same for test)

But,

1. ```
   for test_size in test_sizes:
       X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
       clf = SVC(C=penalty, probability=False)
   ```

   Suppose I have a code like this. In this case, I am changing the `test_size` in each loop. How will it effect what `random_state` does? Will it shuffle everything OR keep as many rows intact as possible and shift a few rows from train to test (or vice versa) according to the test size?
2. Also, `random_state` is a parameter for some classifiers like `sklearn.svm.SVC` and `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`. I have a code like this:

   ```
   clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
   scores = cross_validate(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=cv)
   cross_val_test_score = round(scores['test_score'].mean(), prec)
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   ```

   **What does `random_state` exactly do here?** Because it is used while defining the classifier. It is not supplied with data yet. I got the following from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html:

> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;
>   If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;
>   If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used
>   by np.random.

3. Suppose the following line is executed multiple times for each of multiple test-sizes:

   ```
   clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
   ```

   If I keep `random_state=int(test_size*100)`, does that mean that for each test-size, the results will come out to be the same? (and for different test-sizes, they will be different?)

   (Here, `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` could be replaced with other classifiers who also use `random_state`, such as `sklearn.svm.SVC`. I assume all classifier use `random_state` in a similar way?)

Comment: 2. `random_state` in the `DecisionTreeClassifier` controls (at least) the order in which the features are permuted, so can affect which feature is chosen to split on. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476032/classification-results-depend-on-random-state) is a nice answer with some addiitonal information on other classifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:** Since you are changing the test size, the random state won't impact the selected rows between test-sizes and that wouldn't necessarily be desired behavior anyways since you are simply trying to get scores based on various sample sizes. What this **will** do for you, is allow you to compare models that use the input data, split by the same random state. The test sets will be the exact same from one loop run to the next. Allowing you to properly compare model performance on the same samples.

**2:** For models such as decision tree classifiers and many others, there are initialization parameters that are set at random. The random state here is ensuring that those parameters are set the exact same from one run to the next, creating reproducible behavior.

**3:** If the test size is different, and you multiply it by 100, then you will be creating different random states for each test set. But from one full run to the next it will create reproducible behavior. You could just as easily set a static value there.

Not all models use random state in the same way as each have different parameters that they are setting at random. For RandomForest, it's selecting random features.. for neural networks it's initializing random weights.. etc.

Comment: Clarification regarding point 1, a specific random state means a specific arrangement of data entries, which is generated randomly. Correct? Also, (I added this part in the question after you answered) what would happen If I keep random_state=int(test_size*100)? Same results for same test_size, and different for different test_sizes?

Comment: Yes that is correct. And I believe I answered the test_size * 100 in 3. above. I noticed you were adding to the question and added my responses. But to reiterate, adding this would give you different random states within a single run, but would still be reproducible from one run to the next as long as the test_size is consistent. (ie you aren't adding or changing the lengths)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this with the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
test_series = pd.Series(range(100))
size30split = train_test_split(test_series,random_state = 42,test_size = .3)
size25split = train_test_split(test_series,random_state = 42,test_size = .25)
common = [element for element in size25split[0] if element in size30split[0]]
print(len(common))
```

This gives an output of 70, indicating that it just moved elements from the test set to the training set.

`train_test_split` creates a random permutation of the rows, and selects based on the first n rows of that permutation, where n is based on the test size.

> What does random_state do here?

When the `DecisionTreeClassifier` object named `clf` is created, it's initialized with its `random_state` attribute set to 0. Note that if you type `print(clf.random_state)`, the value `0` will be printed. When you call methods of clf, such as `clf.fit`, those methods may use the `random_state` attribute as a parameter.